# Preposição “a” + infinitivo com sentido de futuro?

Tags: verbos

Sou brasileiro e já fui muito criticado por familiares por usar preposição *a* + *infinitivo* como substituto do gerúndio, me dizendo que *a* + *infinitivo* tem sentido de futuro; ex.: “a mulher a falar foi roubada” seria equivalente a “a mulher que estava para falar foi roubada” ou “a mulher que ia falar foi roubada”.

Dou outros quatro exemplos para esclarecer (ou “[…] quatro exemplos a esclarecer”):

1. “Pessoas a falar sempre há, mas nunca falando” = “pessoas para falar sempre há, mas nunca falando”;
2. “O copo a cair no chão foi resgatado pelo garçom” = “o copo que estava para cair no chão foi resgatado pelo garçom” ou “o copo que ia cair no chão foi resgatado pelo garçom”;
3. “Ele está a fazer há três anos” = “ele está para fazer há três anos” ou “ele 'fará' há três anos”;
4. “Senhor, eu estou a fazer pra você. Entrego amanhã” =, ambos no sentido de obrigação, “senhor, eu farei pra você. Entrego amanhã”, ou melhor “eu hei de fazer pra você. Entrego amanhã”.

Então pergunto: eu já vi muitíssimo este uso, mas ele é comum? Em Portugal teria a mesma interpretação, já que lá é comuníssimo usar *a* + *infinitivo* substituindo o gerúndio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, ***a* + infinitivo** pode indicar um evento futuro, mas em Portugal nenhum dos teus exemplos teria a interpretação que tu lhe dás. Cito o *Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa* (2001), o único foi onde encontrei isto tratado. O ponto 4 é o mais diretamente relevante (grafia anterior ao AO90):

> **a⁵** [ɐ] *prep*. […] **B** Funções gramaticais […] **III** Em relação com um nome ou pronome, antecedendo um infinitivo, indica: **1.** Acção prolongada. *Encontrei-o a falar com um amigo. Vi um homem a ler o jornal*. **2.** Valor enfático. *Foi ele a saudar o homenageado*. **3.**  Dever ou conveniência. *Este é um livro a ler atentamente*. **4.** Tempo futuro. *«Em determinadas pessoas* [os sonhos] *representam fenómenos ainda por estudar […], sucedidos ou a suceder no domínio da natureza.»* (AQUILINO, *Batalha*, p. 107)

Mesmo no ponto 3 pode haver uma ideia de futuro: o que convém ou se deve fazer refere-se normalmente a ações futuras. Na verdade há uma certa continuidade entre os pontos 3 e 4: do que convém ou se deve fazer, passando pelo que se quer fazer, pelo que está decidido ou programado fazer-se, até ao simples futuro:

> Este é um **livro a ler** atentamente
> Informe-se dos **cuidados a ter** no manuseamento deste produto
> Fiz uma lista dos **lugares a visitar** em Londres
> Já afixei os cartazes dos **filmes a exibir** na próxima semana
> O **último a sair** que apague a luz

Agora, por vezes, se isto indica futuro ou passado depende do contexto: por exemplo, *a sair* é no futuro em *o último a sair apague a luz*, mas no passado em *o último a sair foi o João*.

Agora, neste uso, pelo menos em Portugal, o ***a* + infinitivo**, vem, como diz o *Dicionário*, “em relação com um nome ou pronome” ― ***livro** a ler, **filmes** a exibir* etc. ― não com um verbo auxiliar; por isso não se confunde com a perífrase verbal ***estar a* + infinitivo**. Em Portugal, o *estar a fazer* dos teus **exemplos 3 e 4** seria sempre interpretado como ’estar fazendo’ (perguntavam-te logo era, *fazer o quê?*):

> **3.** Ele está a fazer há três anos = ele está fazendo há três anos; exemplo: ele está a fazer (está fazendo) o curso há 6 anos, e ainda está longe de acabar.

Para a interpretação que pretendes, em Portugal seria: *ele está **para** fazer isso há três anos (mas nunca mais começa)*. Do mesmo modo:

> **4.** Estou a fazer para você = estou fazendo para você

Esta perífrase verbal tem sentido de futuro é em coisas do tipo, ***Ana está a fazer anos/a fazer 50 anos*** ou ***está a fazer dois meses que ele chegou***,  em que *está a fazer* significa ’vai fazer (nos próximos dias)’. Mas isto é mesmo só com períodos de tempo: *estou a fazer o jantar* significa apenas ’estou fazendo o jantar’, nunca ’vou fazer’. Pelo que vi na net esta construção é muito mais comum em Portugal do que no Brasil. Eu até pensei que no Brasil se dissesse *está fazendo X anos/meses* com o mesmo significado, mas encontro na net muitas coisas do tipo *está fazendo 50 anos hoje*; em Portugal diríamos *faz 50 anos hoje*, não *está a fazer*.

Também dizemos *estou a chegar* quando ainda estamos a uns minutos de distância; *o filme está a começar* quando já apareceu o logotipo do estúdio, mas antes das primeiras cenas; ou *o azeite está a acabar* quando ainda há um decilitro na garrafa. Mas creio que nestas situações no Brasil também se dirá *estou chegando, está começando, está acabando*.

Os teus **exemplos 1 e 2** em Portugal soariam estranhos:

> **1.** Pessoas a falar sempre há, mas nunca falando

Este geraria perplexidade, porque *pessoas a falar* seria imediatamente interpretado como ’pessoas falando’ (ponto 1 do *Dicionário*). A noção de futuro é possível, mas em coisas como, *de acordo com o programa, as pessoas a falar a seguir são a Ana e o João*.

> **2.** O copo a cair no chão foi resgatado pelo garçom

Aqui interpretaríamos como ’o copo em queda’ (novamente, ponto 1 do *Dicionário*). Para a tua interpretação diríamos, *o copo quase/prestes a cair* ou *em risco de cair*. Mas há situações algo parecidas em que a interpretação é de futuro. Depende do contexto. Por exemplo:

> Os defensores do património arquitetónico querem salvar a **casa a demolir** (que alguém pretende, decidiu, demolir). A **casa a demolir** é agora a **casa a proteger** (que se quer proteger)

Comment: Será que você teria a gentileza de rever as frases na pergunta? Estou de acordo com a sua explicação mas não com as frases acima (na pergunta).

Comment: @Lambie, feito. Na verdade eu logo que postei fiquei vai não vai para comentar os exemplos. O teu pedido foi o incentivozinho que faltava.

Comment: Re: _"Mas creio que nestas situações no Brasil também se dirá estou chegando, está começando, está acabando."_ Confirmo.

Comment: Jacinto, muito obrigado pela resposta. Eu achei que a pergunta fosse não ter resposta até o fim do mundo.

Comment: @Schilive, pois, eu já conhecia a pergunta, mas creio que só agora é que me lembrei de consultar o Dicionário da Academia. O Houaiss não cobre estes usos.