# A sintaxe de orações reduzidas de infinitivo em literatura clássica portuguesa/brasileira

Tags: português-brasileiro, português-europeu

Pois bem, estou com dúvidas de como posso quebrar esta barreira da linguagem/sintaxe para lê-los (Herculano, Camilo, Machado, entre outros). Quais possibilidades de reduzidas eram mais comum à época? Tenho lido Bechara, e confirmado que são sintaxes hoje pouco usuais. Em suma, gostaria de saber quais orações reduzidas de infinitivo as principais preposições introduzem (a, para, em e com). Confira alguns exemplos:

- > Livros a consultar. (adjetiva restritiva? seria comutável por 'para'?)
- > O primeiro em/a chegar. (e aqui seria?)
- > Dois meios havia em seguir esta empresa. (à luz de Bechara seria final).
- > até o (D. Afonso) induzirem a mandá-lo (D. Pedro) sair da corte, ao que D. Pedro atalhou 'com retirar-se' antes que lho ordenassem. (o
  > autor levanta a ideia de meio/instrumento).
- > Porém, deixando o coração cativo,/ com fazer-te a meus rogos sempre humano,/ fugiste-me traidor... (causal)
- > Em verdade, bem louco deve ser este homem 'em estar a plantar' agora esta nogueira, como se estivesse ainda no vigor da mocidade”
  > (causal conforme o autor, também vejo a possibilidade de adjetiva, e,
  > a propósito, por quais preposições as adjetivas introduzem-se nas reduzidas de
  > infinitivo?).

Bom, para não me alongar com exemplos deixo estes, em síntese quais seriam as OSRI possíveis de encontrar com tais preposições? Aliás, há alguma recomendação de como lê-los? Agradeço-lhes pela atenção.

Comment: Desculpe, eu não entendi. Quer saber como fazer a análise sintática dessas frases, ou ainda do uso que lhe parece estranho das preposições *em* e *a*? Talvez [isto](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/8269/preposi%c3%a7%c3%a3o-a-infinitivo-com-sentido-de-futuro) seja de alguma ajuda.

Comment: A análise destas, mas também o uso das preposições mencionadas introduzindo reduzidas de infinitivo quais poderiam introduzir adjetivas, adverbiais, etc. Quanto ao link eu já havia lido kk. Também estava com uma dúvida semelhante à sua. Creio que em 'a mulher a falar foi roubada' você tenha pensado analogamente à construção 'a mulher a estar por/para/a falar foi roubada'. Acho que o aspecto de iminência com as reduzidas só há de possível ser com 'prestes/próximo + a' etc.